# How do I embed ~< ! date within Unix Mailx message?

Tags: unix, mailx

~! date would invoke the date command while mailx is in input mode.

~< ! date invokes the date command and would include the date within the mailx message.

Hypothetically if I wanted to send a message with the date

mailx -s "Test the date" TestUser123

Where would I insert the ~< ! date command?

Answer (score 0):

```
mailx -s "Test the date `date`" TestUser123
```

That puts the current date in the subject  Note the backtics around the date command.

```
date | mailx -s "Test the date" TestUser123
```

That puts the date in the body of the email text.